# JQuery datePicker dateFormat not changing

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am trying to use the datepicker for first time. I am trying to change the format to **dd-mm-yyyy** but it's not working! it's still showing as **mm/dd/yyyy**. How can I fix this please?

in :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() { $( "#dateBirthday" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yyyy" }) });
</script>
```

in :

```
<input type="date" id="dateBirthday" name="dateBirthday" min="1920-01-01" max="1990-01-01" value="<?php echo $member_date_of_birth; ?>" autocomplete="off" required>
```

Thanks,

[Jassim](http://www.JassimRahma.com/)

Comment: Did you refresh your page after making changes?

Answer (score 0):

First

> **why you need `jQuery datePicker`, when you use `HTML5 Datepicker`?**

I will affect each other as shown in the image.

[image]

Rather you should try this

**HTML:**

```
<input  type="text" id="dateBirthday" name="dateBirthday"  value="<?php echo $member_date_of_birth; ?>" autocomplete="off" required>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $("#dateBirthday").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"     // this is the format returns 17-08-2013
    })
});
```

Check this in [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dN54p/)